# help() with unicode __author__ string

Tags: python, character-encoding, author, pydoc

In the beginning of my scripts in Python 2.6, I would like to write my name as it is spelled, i.e. "Joël" (with trema on e). So I write `__author__ = u'Joël'`, and I can retrieve it by a simple `print __author__`.

Problem appears with the built-in `help()` function, as I get an error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xeb' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I cannot upgrade to Python 3.x, and I find this function very helpful (and it will surely be for those who will get my scripts). I also did not forget to encode the files in UTF-8, and to specify it in the scripts by adding this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Any idea on where this comes from?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

---

EDIT
Looking to the "Dive Into Python" book again, I found out how to have a correct render on my machine, see http://www.diveintopython.org/xml_processing/unicode.html.

The idea is that, my default encoding for Python was ASCII, and this did prevent help() to make a correct output. What I did is to add a script named like `sitecustomize.py` in `{pythondir}\Lib\site-packages`, setting the default encoding:

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('iso-8859-1')
```

And now, with an input string written like `u'Joël'`, I get a correct output through call of help().

Problem is, I'm quite sure that this will break on other's computers. Any idea how I could handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Pydoc explicitly wants to convert the author name to ascii:

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 1111, in docmodule
    result = result + self.section('AUTHOR', str(object.__author__))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xeb' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It’s unlikely that you can work around this.

Comment: Sure it is. Just replace it with an object with a custom `__str__()` method.

Comment: I'm just trying this, but I don't know what to put inside this `__str__()` methode. I mean, putting some encoding conversion here, for example for accent removing, seems the same as writing my name without accent from the very beginning, as any `print` will call it. Or, I should see how to be able to change the output depending on the calling function... not sure this is legal.

Comment: @Ignacio It expects a string of bytes regardless. And `sys.getdefaultencoding` unhelpfully says `'ascii'`.

Comment: Well with my little knowledge, I see no solution. Could I consider this as a bug in help() function?

Comment: I found out how to solve this (at least on my machine...), see my answer below. Any comments will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a simple string and not a Unicode string. Therefore:

```
__author__ = 'Joël'
```

The built-in help method then displays:

```
AUTHOR
    Joël
```

Edit: If this doesn't work, then you can force returning a 8-bit string version of your name by doing this:

```
 __author__ = u'Joël'.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: I worry that this will not be cross platform, as it depends on the platform’s default encoding.

Comment: Good idea, I did not try this before. Alas, it does not work as good as I would like it to do: on my own computer in IDLE, configured in UTF-8, I get `JoÃ«l`. Weird.  And if I come back to explicit unicode string, no problem anywhere but with help().